# Store values to an array from a text file

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

Please advise how can i read and store values from a text file to an array in Selenium IDE (+ sideflow extension).

I have the following script:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>new Array(&quot;1&quot;,&quot;2&quot;,&quot;3&quot;,&quot;4&quot;,&quot;5&quot;,&quot;6&quot;);</td>
    <td>nums</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>i = 0;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>i &lt; storedVars['nums'].length</td>
    <td></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=m</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['nums'][i]}</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>name=submit</td>
    <td></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=t</td>
    <td></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=s1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=td.tbl-actions &gt; input[name=&quot;submit&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>document.ConfirmForm.submit[1]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=k</td>
    <td></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>i++;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>endWhile</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>alert(&quot;Done!&quot;);</td>
    <td></td></tr>
```

I have a local text file with values in one column:

1
2
3
4
5
6

I assume that it is very simple, but i am new to this and would be very thankful for any kind of assistance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not exactly what you are asking but i have a related answer in my mind,

```
command:store

target:newArray{['value1','value2','value3']}

value:myVariable
```

this will randomly select any of the value and store it in myvariable

or if you wanted to use array for it, I have a perfect code

```
command:storeEval
target:new Array("item0","item1", "item2", "item3");
value:list
```

you cam access these using command:getEval target:list